# Javascript not executing on pressing calculate button

Tags: javascript, calculation

Trying to create calculator to calculate difference in size and output result

This is the script using.

Script used to calculate in suze basis diameter
Check out on - https://code.sololearn.com/wahq9E8aL5I3

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   function getVal(ctrlid){
 var e = document.getElementById(ctrlid);
  var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  return result
 }
 function SetVal(ctrlid,values){
 document.getElementById(ctrlid).value=values;
 }
 function Calculate1 (  ) {
 section1=getVal("section1")
 profile1=getVal("profile1")
 diameter1=getVal("diameter1")

         rollingradius1=Math.round((((diameter1/2)*25.4)+(section1*(profile1/100)))*100)/100;

     circumference1=Math.round((rollingradius1*2*3.14159)*100)/100;
      SetVal("rollingradius1",rollingradius1)
  SetVal("circumference1",circumference1)       
      }

function getVal(ctrlid2){

 var e2 = document.getElementById(ctrlid2);
  var result = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
  return result
 }
 function SetVal(ctrlid2,values){
 document.getElementById(ctrlid2).value=values;
 }

 function Calculate2 (  ) {
 section2=getVal("section2")
 profile2=getVal("profile2")
 diameter2=getVal("diameter2")

         rollingradius2=Math.round((((diameter2/2)*25.4)+(section2*(profile2/100)))*100)/100;

     circumference2=Math.round((rollingradius2*2*3.14159)*100)/100;
      SetVal("rollingradius2",rollingradius2)
  SetVal("circumference2",circumference2)       
      }      

      function Difference ( circumference1, circumference2 ) {
         difference=Math.round((circumference2-circumference1)*100)/100;
         differencepercent=Math.round(((difference/circumference1)*100)*100)/100;
         realspeed=Math.round((((differencepercent/100)*70)+70)*100)/100;
         document.wheelsizes.difference.value=difference;
         document.wheelsizes.differencepercent.value=differencepercent;
         document.wheelsizes.realspeed.value=realspeed;
      }
    </script>
```

and the form is

```
   <table border=0 align="CENTER">
        <tr>
            <th align=CENTER>Current wheel/tyre</th>
            <th align=CENTER>New wheel/tyre</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER><select name="section1">
            <option value="195">190</option>
            <option value="195">195</option>
            <option value="205">205</option>
            <option value="215">215</option>
                            </select>
            /
            <select name="profile1">
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="65" selected>65</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="75">75</option>
            <option value="80">80</option>
            </select>
            R
            <select name="diameter1">
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="16.5">16.5</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align=CENTER>
            <select name="section2">
            <option value="195">190</option>
            <option value="195">195</option>
            <option value="205">205</option>
            <option value="215">215</option>
            </select>
            /
            <select name="profile2">
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="65" selected>65</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="75">75</option>
            <option value="80">80</option>
            </select>
            R
            <select name="diameter2">
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="16.5">16.5</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER>
        <input type="button" name="calc1" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate1()">
        </td>
        <td align=CENTER>
        <input type="button" name="calc2" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate2()">
        </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER>Current RR:<input type="text" name="rollingradius1" size=7>mm</td>
            <td align=CENTER>New RR:<input type="text" name="rollingradius2" size=7>mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER>Current circumference:<input type="text" name="circumference1" size=7>mm</td>
            <td align=CENTER>New circumference:<input type="text" name="circumference2" size=7>mm</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=CENTER>
            <input type="button" name="yo" value="Click to calculate difference" onclick="Difference(document.wheelsizes.circumference1.value, document.wheelsizes.circumference2.value)">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=CENTER>
            Difference in circumference:<input type="text" name="difference" size=8>mm or <input type="text" name="differencepercent" size=5>%
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Although this is a working calculator in some site, but am unable to get any result on pressing calculate button
Any advise to get it working
The second calculate button is not working, as tried again

Comment: what is the problem? what did you do so far?

Comment: Tried on - https://code.sololearn.com/wahq9E8aL5I3  , but no result on pressing submit button

Comment: check console error if there are resolve it

Comment: @have you checked it? `document.wheelsizes is undefined`

Comment: Oh yes, actually trying to create a replica with some modification as given on  tyrestore.in/upsizing.htm . but seems not entire code and hence failing. any pointers to get it working

Comment: @Ruchika document.wheelsizes is not object why are you passing that to Calculate function just get value from section1 select box and pass that exact value or just pass name of profile

Comment: Wrapping your whole table in ```<form name="wheelsizes">``` will solve the ```document.wheelsizes``` undefined issue. But still there might be errors since you are using values like ```document.wheelsizes.realspeed``` in your JS code but there are no input field named ```realspeed``` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code it is completely reproduced

```js
function getVal(ctrlid){

 var e = document.getElementById(ctrlid);
  var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  return result
 }
 function SetVal(ctrlid,values){
 document.getElementById(ctrlid).value=values;
 }

 function Calculate1 (  ) {
 section1=getVal("section1")
 profile1=getVal("profile1")
 diameter1=getVal("diameter1")

         rollingradius1=Math.round((((diameter1/2)*25.4)+(section1*(profile1/100)))*100)/100;

     circumference1=Math.round((rollingradius1*2*3.14159)*100)/100;
      SetVal("rollingradius1",rollingradius1)
  SetVal("circumference1",circumference1)   
      }


       function Calculate2 (  ) {
 section2=getVal("section2")
 profile2=getVal("profile2")
 diameter2=getVal("diameter2")

         rollingradius2=Math.round((((diameter2/2)*25.4)+(section2*(profile2/100)))*100)/100;

     circumference2=Math.round((rollingradius2*2*3.14159)*100)/100;
      SetVal("rollingradius2",rollingradius2)
  SetVal("circumference2",circumference2)       
      }



        function Difference () {
            circumference1=document.getElementById("circumference1").value
            circumference2=document.getElementById("circumference2").value
         difference=Math.round((circumference2-circumference1)*100)/100;
         differencepercent=Math.round(((difference/circumference1)*100)*100)/100;
         realspeed=Math.round((((differencepercent/100)*70)+70)*100)/100;
         
         SetVal("difference",difference)  
         SetVal("differencepercent",differencepercent) 
         console.log("realspeed:",realspeed)   
      }
```

```html
<table border=0 align="CENTER">
        <tr>
            <th align=CENTER>Current wheel/tyre</th>
            <th align=CENTER>New wheel/tyre</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td align=CENTER><select name="section1" id="section1">
            <option value="195">190</option>
            <option value="195">195</option>
            <option value="205">205</option>
            <option value="215">215</option>
                            </select>
            /
            <select name="profile1" id="profile1">
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="65" selected>65</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="75">75</option>
            <option value="80">80</option>
            </select>
            R
            <select name="diameter1" id="diameter1">
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="16.5">16.5</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align=CENTER><select name="section2" id="section2">
            <option value="195">190</option>
            <option value="195">195</option>
            <option value="205">205</option>
            <option value="215">215</option>
                            </select>
            /
            <select name="profile2" id="profile2">
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="65" selected>65</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="75">75</option>
            <option value="80">80</option>
            </select>
            R
            <select name="diameter2" id="diameter2">
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="16.5">16.5</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER>
        <input type="button" name="calc1" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate1()">
        </td>
        <td align=CENTER>
        <input type="button" name="calc2" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate2()">
        </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER>Current RR:<input type="text" name="rollingradius1" size=7 id="rollingradius1">mm</td>
            <td align=CENTER>New RR:<input type="text" name="rollingradius2" size=7 id="rollingradius2">mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=CENTER>Current circumference:<input type="text" name="circumference1" id="circumference1" size=7>mm</td>
            <td align=CENTER>New circumference:<input type="text" name="circumference2" id="circumference2" size=7>mm</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=CENTER>
            <input type="button" name="yo" value="Click to calculate difference" onclick="Difference()">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=CENTER>
            Difference in circumference:<input type="text" name="difference" size=8 id="difference">mm or <input type="text" name="differencepercent" id="differencepercent" size=5>%
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. I am novice and learning. Tried creating calculate2 but again stuck -

Comment: added code in question, can you advise again if possible. thanks

Comment: for section 2 define ids and change function calling same as calculate1()

Comment: Thanks trying on https://code.sololearn.com/wahq9E8aL5I3 - but still something a  miss